# Event not triggering correctly

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Here is my code:

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {

       $app = $e->getParam('application');
       $app->getEventManager()->attach('pre.loadevents',array($this,'preLoadEvents'));
       $app->getEventManager()->attach('loadevents',array($this,'loadEvents'));
       $app->getEventManager()->attach('post.loadevents',array($this,'postLoadEvents'));
       $app->getEventManager()->trigger('loadevents',null,[]);
    }       

    public function preLoadEvents(MvcEvent $e)
    {

    }

    public function postLoadEvents(MvcEvent $e)
    {

    }

    public function loadEvents(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $eventsConfig = yoda::config('module/application/events/event');
        foreach($eventsConfig as $event){
            if((int)$event->active===0)continue;
            $app->getEventManager()->attach($event->name,array($this,$event->method));
        }

    }
}
```

Upon using this I get `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Application\Module::loadEvents() must be an instance of Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent, instance of Zend\EventManager\Event given`. **What am I doing incorrectly**

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
public function loadEvents(\Zend\EventManager\Event $e)
{
   ...
}
```

instead of

```
public function loadEvents(MvcEvent $e)
{
   ...
}
```

because it is not a MVC event you are getting here.